# How to set the range sliders (w-3schoool example)?

Tags: php, css

I’m setting up some range sliders in my web application, and want to show the value for each slider.

(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_rangeslider_round)

I’m setting up some range sliders
I want to 
display the value for each slider individually
update the current slider value individually
(each time you drag the slider handle)

i can achieve the above task, but it is messy if i need to handle more than 20 sliders.

Is there any better methods for doing that?

I don't want to keep repeating the function like that:
    ...("myRange2").oninput = function() {
      .......
    }
    ...("myRange3").oninput = function() {
      ...("output3").....;
    }
    .
    .
    ...("myRange20").oninput = function() {
      ........;
    }

```
enter code here

<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100"  name="LEFT_EQ_BAND1" value="<?php 
echo $row['LEFT_EQ_BAND1'];?>" class="slider" id="myRange0">
<p>Value: <span id="output0"></span></p>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100"  name="LEFT_EQ_BAND2" value="<?php 
echo $row['LEFT_EQ_BAND1'];?>" class="slider" id="myRange1">
<p>Value: <span id="output1"></span></p>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100"  name="LEFT_EQ_BAND3" value="<?php 
echo $row['LEFT_EQ_BAND1'];?>" class="slider" id="myRange2">
<p>Value: <span id="output2"></span></p>
</div>

enter code here

<script>
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"+i);
var output = document.getElementById("output"+i);
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

}

document.getElementById("myRange0").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("output0").innerHTML = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("myRange1").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("myRange2").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = this.value;
}
.
.
.
.
document.getElementById("myRange19").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("output19").innerHTML = this.value;
}
.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you want to display each slider value individually. For that, here's the code-

```
<body>

<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange1">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange3">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo3"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slider3 = document.getElementById("myRange3");
var output3 = document.getElementById("demo3");
output3.innerHTML = slider3.value;

slider3.oninput = function() {
  output3.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Please ellaborate your question if the answer is not correct!

Comment: so, if slide1 is drag to 50, then slider1 value should show 50. if slide2 is drag to 40, then slider2 value should show 40 and so on...do you want like this?? if not, can you provide example for me to understand what you want?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to keep repeating the function (range 1 to range 20 or more).